# C++ very simple network trigger (library, code)

Tags: c++, networking, triggers, tcp, udp

Hey guys!
I'm looking for a simple code sniplet or library to make my (still lightweight) c++ program (Windows XP, Visual Studio 2008) receive (local) network signals. It should be like this: another program is sending a tcp/udp packet - my program is calling a function triggered() then..
Any suggestions?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: An obligatory question - what state is your program in while it's waiting for packets to arrive? Is it sleeping, or running a message loop, or doing something completely unrelated? Do you want to process triggers in the main thread or in an alternative one?

Comment: I'm running in a noop loop with window handling...

Answer (score 4):

Have you taken a look at Boost.Asio? It will allow you listen for the signal over the network packet and automatically call a handler whenever you receive data over the network.

Comment: its not the most lightweight thing in the world but it still usually outperforms anything I try to roll myself.